# Parallel SELECT query for sqlite file

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have database stored in sqlite file and some of the `select` queries return millions of rows. I would like to write a parallel application where each process will :

1. Open the sqlite file separately (read-only)
2. Run a query that will return only a part of the rows
3. Process the rows in each process

My question is on the second part of the algorithm. How can I alter my `SELECT` statement so that it will return a part of the rows?

I thought about `OFFSET`/`LIMIT` but this would imply that I know the number of the final rows, which I don't. Plus the runtime of the query is significant and I wouldn't like to run the same query twice in order to get the total of rows.

Comment: Without seeing your table schema, it's really hard to give any suggestions. You might start by reading https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results though.

Answer (score 0):

Considering

> I thought about OFFSET/LIMIT but this would imply that I know the
>   number of the final rows, which I don't.

You could maintain a count by having a minuscule table with a single row per table to be counted with two columns, the tablename (wouldn't be need if only one table) and the count. Two TRIGGERS could automatically maintain the count.

An alternative but similarly not that intensive (to ascertain an idea of the count) , if you use AUTOINCREMENT, would be to get a guestimate (max possible without any deletions) by access the seq column, for the table of the **sqlite_sequence** table.

Perhaps consider the following example of both :-

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS newmain1row;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS deletedmain1row;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rowcount;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, mycolumn TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, mycolumn TEXT); -- is it slower/faster than 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rowcount (tablename TEXT PRIMARY KEY, rowcount INTEGER) WITHOUT ROWID;
INSERT INTO rowcount VALUES('main1',0); -- initialise rowcount table

-- Trigger for when a new row is added to the table
CREATE TRIGGER newmain1row 
    AFTER INSERT ON main1 BEGIN 
        UPDATE rowcount SET rowcount = rowcount + 1 WHERE tablename = 'main1';
    END
;

-- Trigger for when a row is deleted from the table
CREATE TRIGGER deletedmain1row
    AFTER DELETE ON main1 BEGIN
      UPDATE rowcount SET rowcount = rowcount - 1 WHERE tablename = 'main1';
    END
;

-- populate the two example main tables twice so in reverse order 2nd time
-- with a million rows so 2 million per table
WITH RECURSIVE cte1(counter) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        UNION ALL SELECT counter+1 FROM cte1 WHERE counter < 1000000
    )
INSERT INTO main1 (mycolumn) SELECT counter FROM cte1
;
WITH RECURSIVE cte1(counter) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        UNION ALL SELECT counter+1 FROM cte1 WHERE counter < 1000000
    )
INSERT INTO main2 (mycolumn) SELECT counter FROM cte1
;

WITH RECURSIVE cte1(counter) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        UNION ALL SELECT counter+1 FROM cte1 WHERE counter < 1000000
    )
INSERT INTO main2 (mycolumn) SELECT counter FROM cte1
;
WITH RECURSIVE cte1(counter) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        UNION ALL SELECT counter+1 FROM cte1 WHERE counter < 1000000
    )
INSERT INTO main1 (mycolumn) SELECT counter FROM cte1
;
-- DELETE 40,000 rows
DELETE FROM main1 WHERE CAST(mycolumn AS INTEGER) % 50 = 0;
DELETE FROM main2 WHERE CAST(mycolumn AS INTEGER) % 50 = 0;
-- get the number of rows
SELECT rowcount FROM rowcount WHERE tablename = 'main1';
SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'main2';
```

This :-

1. DROPS the TRIGGERS and TABLES allowing it to be rerun.
2. CREATES THE 2 main TABLES (main1 and main2) for each method i.e. both basically the same except the latter with AUTOINCREMENT
3. CREATES the counter table for the first approach and adds a row with a count of 0 for the main1 table
4. CREATES the 2 TRIGGERS for when the first (main1) table has a row inserted (increments the count) and for when a row is deleted (decrements the count).
5. inserts 2,000,000 rows into each table in 4 batches of 1,000,000 rows, reversing the order, for perhaps a better idea of timing.
6. deletes 40,000 rows from each table.
7. retrieve the counts from each (note that the count returned from the 2nd method is 2,000,000 instead of 1,960,000 as that is the last allocated id).

The log :-

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS newmain1row
> OK
> Time: 0.187s


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS deletedmain1row
> OK
> Time: 0.084s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rowcount
> OK
> Time: 0.153s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main1
> OK
> Time: 2.534s


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main2
> OK
> Time: 2.547s


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, mycolumn TEXT)
> OK
> Time: 0.158s


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, mycolumn TEXT)
> OK
> Time: 0.167s


-- is it slower/faster than 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rowcount (tablename TEXT PRIMARY KEY, rowcount INTEGER) WITHOUT ROWID
> OK
> Time: 0.167s


INSERT INTO rowcount VALUES('main1',0)
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.165s


-- initialise rowcount table

-- Trigger for when a new row is added to the table
CREATE TRIGGER newmain1row 
    AFTER INSERT ON main1 BEGIN 
        UPDATE rowcount SET rowcount = rowcount + 1 WHERE tablename = 'main1';
    END
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.086s


-- Trigger for when a row is deleted from the table
CREATE TRIGGER deletedmain1row
    AFTER DELETE ON main1 BEGIN
      UPDATE rowcount SET rowcount = rowcount - 1 WHERE tablename = 'main1';
    END
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.096s


-- populate the two example main tables twice so in reverse order 2nd time
-- with a million rows so 2 million per table
WITH RECURSIVE cte1(counter) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        UNION ALL SELECT counter+1 FROM cte1 WHERE counter < 1000000
    )
INSERT INTO main1 (mycolumn) SELECT counter FROM cte1
> Affected rows: 1000000
> Time: 1.199s


WITH RECURSIVE cte1(counter) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        UNION ALL SELECT counter+1 FROM cte1 WHERE counter < 1000000
    )
INSERT INTO main2 (mycolumn) SELECT counter FROM cte1
> Affected rows: 1000000
> Time: 0.811s


WITH RECURSIVE cte1(counter) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        UNION ALL SELECT counter+1 FROM cte1 WHERE counter < 1000000
    )
INSERT INTO main2 (mycolumn) SELECT counter FROM cte1
> Affected rows: 1000000
> Time: 1.058s


WITH RECURSIVE cte1(counter) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        UNION ALL SELECT counter+1 FROM cte1 WHERE counter < 1000000
    )
INSERT INTO main1 (mycolumn) SELECT counter FROM cte1
> Affected rows: 1000000
> Time: 1.177s


DELETE FROM main1 WHERE CAST(mycolumn AS INTEGER) % 50 = 0
> Affected rows: 40000
> Time: 2.82s


DELETE FROM main2 WHERE CAST(mycolumn AS INTEGER) % 50 = 0
> Affected rows: 40000
> Time: 2.649s


-- get the number of rows
SELECT rowcount FROM rowcount WHERE tablename = 'main1'
> OK
> Time: 0s


SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'main2'
> OK
> Time: 0s
```

The total time taken being a little over 16 seconds.

The 2 results are 1.960,000 and 2,000,000 respectively.